# How to prevent US post code formats

Tags: validation

I have an issue with American and Canada postcodes in accounts and contacts. Some of the users are creating the salesforce records with postcodes like (MD 20904), when we sending post code from salesforce to SAP integration, SAP system is rejecting salesforce records as postcode is not in correct format.

My question is:

1. what are actual US and canada post code formats?
2. If Users are creating the post codes with MD 20904, how would prevent through validation rule like only accept sepecific format?

Comment: Please follow this link - http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx. You can validate  users' input against these regex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

> what are actual US and Canada post code formats

[Canada post code format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada), [US post code format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code).

K1A 0B1 would be an example of Canadian post code format and 10005 would be an example of US Post Code.

> If Users are creating the post codes with MD 20904, how would prevent through validation rule like only accept specific format?

You'd want to look at a validation rule with Regular Expressions (REGEX) for this but that would really depend on what exactly you wanted to do. Do you want to only allow Canadian-style Post Codes? Do you want to explicitly reject US Post Codes?

As Santanu commented, the link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200729205115/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx) can help you get the regex for Canadian and US Postal/Zip codes. But you can find regexes anywhere on the web for anything pretty easily with a cheeky Google search.

Here's an example REGEX formula for use within Salesforce validation rules:

```
NOT(
  OR(
    ISBLANK(Post_Code__c),
    REGEX( Post_Code__c, "[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$")
  )
)
```

This would check whether or not your field `Post_Code__c` is blank and matches the Canadian Post Code format.